# Why line 27 is executed before line 24?

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, ecmascript-6

I m beginner with javascript and try to build a clean object to use the Dockerode library in my use Case. I have an async problem here my line 27 executes before 24 and I don't understand why and how to fix it!

Also if it's easier for you, please visit this public gist: https://gist.github.com/msitruk/2cdb655a0bebdb29c61d8bc5606a2695

```
const Docker = require('dockerode');
const docker = new Docker({
    socketPath: '/var/run/docker.sock'
});

// CONSTRUCTOR
function SearchUtils() {
    this.listContainersPromise = docker.listContainers({all: true});
    this.scraperListId = [];
}

// "METHODS"
SearchUtils.prototype.run = function() {
    this.getScraperContainersListPromise()
        .then((containers) => {
            for (let i = 0; i < containers.length; i++) {
                if (containers[i].Names.toString().indexOf("scraper") !== -1) {
                    this.addToScraperList(containers[i].Id, "wait");
                }
            }
        }, (err)=>{console.log(err)})
        .then(()=>{
            this.checkReadyScraper();
        },(err)=>{console.log(err)})
        .then(() => {
            this.scrap();
        }, (err)=>{console.log(err)});
};

SearchUtils.prototype.checkReadyScraper = function() {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.scraperListId.length; i++) {
        this.exec("getStatus", this.scraperListId[i].id);
    }
};

SearchUtils.prototype.getScraperContainersListPromise = function() {
    return this.listContainersPromise; // <- Not working
};

SearchUtils.prototype.exec = function(type, containerId){
    let container = docker.getContainer(containerId);
    if (type === "getStatus"){
        this.runExec(container, 'cat /home/immobot/status');
    }
    else if (type === "scrap") {
        this.runExec(container, 'torify scrapy crawl seloger -o seloger.json');
    }
};

SearchUtils.prototype.scrap = function() {
    let localRdyScraperList = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < this.scraperListId.length; i++) {
        if(this.scraperListId[i].status.toString('utf8').indexOf("ready") !== -1){
            localRdyScraperList.push(this.scraperListId[i].id);
        }
    }
    console.log("test de localRdyScraperList : "+localRdyScraperList);
    // this.exec("scrap", this.scraperListId[i].id);
};

SearchUtils.prototype.addToScraperList = function(containerId,status) {
    this.scraperListId.push({id: containerId, status: status});
};

SearchUtils.prototype.getScraperList = function() {
    return this.scraperListId;
};

SearchUtils.prototype.getScraperList = function() {
    return this.scraperListId;
};

SearchUtils.prototype.runExec = function (container, cmd) {
    let options = {
        Cmd: [ '/bin/bash', '-c', cmd ],
        AttachStdout: true,
        AttachStderr: true
    };

    container.exec(options, (err, exec) => {
        if (err) return;
        exec.start((err, stream) => {
            if (err){
                console.log("error : "+err);
                return;
            }

            // container.modem.demuxStream(stream, process.stdout, process.stderr)

            if (cmd === "cat /home/immobot/status"){
                let newStream = require('stream');
                let logStream = new newStream.PassThrough();
                logStream.on('data', (chunk) => {
                    // console.log(chunk.toString('utf8'));
                    if (chunk.toString('utf8').indexOf("ready") !== -1){
                        console.log("CONTAINER READY !!");
                        //EDIT CONTAINER STATUS IN SCRAPERLIST TO READY
                        this.changeStatusToReady(container.id);
                    }
                });
                container.modem.demuxStream(stream, logStream, process.stderr);

            }
            else if (cmd === "torify scrapy crawl seloger -o seloger.json"){
                console.log("on lance le scrape sur un des scraper rdy");
                container.modem.demuxStream(stream, process.stdout, process.stderr)
            }

            // container.modem.demuxStream(stream, logStream, process.stderr);

            exec.inspect(function(err, data) {
                if (err){
                    console.log("error : "+err);
                    return;
                }
            });
        });
    });
};

SearchUtils.prototype.changeStatusToReady = function (containerId){
    for (let i = 0; i < this.scraperListId.length; i++) {
        if(this.scraperListId[i].id === containerId){
            this.scraperListId[i].status = "ready";
        }
    }
    // console.log(this.getScraperList());
};

module.exports = SearchUtils;
```

Comment: is `container.exec` sync or async?

Comment: and you mean if you add console logs before at line 24 and 27, the second one is called first?

Comment: container.exec <- I m not able to answer but think yes

Comment: if I add a console.log i get :                                                                 
    2017-09-13T10:36:00.124997208Z 25
    2017-09-13T10:36:00.125458477Z test de localRdyScraperList :
    2017-09-13T10:36:00.125508120Z 29
    2017-09-13T10:36:00.167946448Z CONTAINER READY !!
    2017-09-13T10:36:00.222466563Z CONTAINER READY !!
    2017-09-13T10:36:00.274632289Z CONTAINER READY !!

Answer (score 3):

If your chaining promises, don't forget to return your next promise..

eg..

```
.then(()=>{
  this.checkReadyScraper();
}
```

If `checkReadyScraper()` is a promise, then you will want to return it.

eg.

```
.then(()=>{
  return this.checkReadyScraper();
}
```

Otherwise all your doing is running `checkReadyScraper()` and totally ignoring the returned Promise.

Here is how I think your runExec should look.  I'm assuming the `exec.inspect` is what you want to resolve on.

```js
SearchUtils.prototype.runExec = function (container, cmd) {
    return new Promise ((resolve, reject)=>{
        let options = {
            Cmd: [ '/bin/bash', '-c', cmd ],
            AttachStdout: true,
            AttachStderr: true
        };

        container.exec(options, (err, exec) => {
            if (err) return reject(err); //return error
            exec.start((err, stream) => {
                if (err){
                    console.log("error : "+err);
                    return reject(err); //return error
                }

                // container.modem.demuxStream(stream, process.stdout, process.stderr)

                if (cmd === "cat /home/immobot/status"){
                    let newStream = require('stream');
                    let logStream = new newStream.PassThrough();
                    logStream.on('data', (chunk) => {
                        // console.log(chunk.toString('utf8'));
                        if (chunk.toString('utf8').indexOf("ready") !== -1){
                            console.log("CONTAINER READY !!");
                            //EDIT CONTAINER STATUS IN SCRAPERLIST TO READY
                            this.changeStatusToReady(container.id);
                        }
                    });
                    container.modem.demuxStream(stream, logStream, process.stderr);

                }
                else if (cmd === "torify scrapy crawl seloger -o seloger.json"){
                    console.log("on lance le scrape sur un des scraper rdy");
                    container.modem.demuxStream(stream, process.stdout, process.stderr)
                }

                // container.modem.demuxStream(stream, logStream, process.stderr);

                exec.inspect(function(err, data) {
                    if (err){
                        console.log("error : "+err);
                        //don't forget to return the rejection
                        return reject(err);
                    }
                    //looks like everything was ok, lets resolve
                    resolve(data);
                });
            });
        });
        //resolve("ok"); too early
        // TODO ADD EROR STRATEGY
        //reject("error"), pointless
    });
};
```

Comment: Because `checkReadyScraper()` is not a promise.. You will need to make sure everything down the line is returning a promise, looking at your gitHub gist, your `exec` is an asynchronous function because it calls runExec, you will need to make  runExec into a promise based function.

Comment: I try but always same thing .. was is wong .. chekc my new revision : https://gist.github.com/msitruk/2cdb655a0bebdb29c61d8bc5606a2695

Comment: if you look at my code, all the errors are just `return reject(err)`,  the place this looks like it gets it's results is in `exec.inspect`, so if no error it resolves the data.  So you was nearly there, your resolves, rejects at the end were too early..

Comment: I understand better but it's not working like I want. I think it's because "exec.inspect" is not what I want to resolv but the entire "container.exec"

Answer (score 0):

Executing a task (with container.exec, on line 81 in your code), runs asynchronious from the rest of your steps, having a callback when they are done.
You would have to make sure all the checks for scrapers are finished before running the scrap command if order matters.

Comment: I think you are right but I can't figure how atm but I continu to investigate on this side !

Comment: I try but always same thing .. was is wong .. chekc my new revision : https://gist.github.com/msitruk/2cdb655a0bebdb29c61d8bc5606a2695

Answer (score 0):

First - there is no need to handle errors in every then() call.
You can implement a single error catch, which will catch error in any then() item in a sequence:

```
.then(()=> {
  this.checkReadyScraper();
})
.then(() => {
  this.scrap();
})
.catch(e => console.log(e))
```

Also note, that arrow function like catch(e => console.log(e)) doesn't require {} and ;

Your problem is that your task is Async. If you want to chain tasks - you should **make a task to return a Promise**

This is a rough exaple what you should refactor:

```
//Should return Promise
SearchUtils.prototype.exec = function(type, containerId){
  let container = docker.getContainer(containerId);
  if (type === "getStatus"){
    //runExec should return us a Promise
    return this.runExec(container, 'cat /home/immobot/status');
  }
  else if (type === "scrap") {
    return this.runExec(container, 'torify scrapy crawl seloger -o seloger.json');
  }
};

SearchUtils.prototype.runExec = function (container, cmd) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
     //do some stuff
     //then call resolve(result)
     //or call reject(error)
  });
}
```

After this, you will be able to chain Promises (which is quite awesome actually and helps to solve callback hell):

```
.then(()=> {
  //this not returns Promise, and it will be correctly chained 
  return this.checkReadyScraper();
})
.then(() => {
  //this not returns Promise, and it will be correctly chained
  return this.scrap();
})
.catch(e => console.log(e))
```

Also, to make this looks cleaner I even recommend to do some small refactoring, which will finally give you oneliner:

```
.then(this.checkReadyScraper).then(this.scrap).catch(console.log)
```

Comment: I try but always same thing .. was is wong .. chekc my new revision : https://gist.github.com/msitruk/2cdb655a0bebdb29c61d8bc5606a2695